# Yii CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]:

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I get this error when I didn't do anything for a while, I'm not sure if this is a Session problem or not.

The error message is:

> **CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=='1')' at line 1. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM `games_developers_app` `t` WHERE (status LIKE :ycp0) AND (developer_id==:ycp1)**

The code is:

```
public function actionSortReject(){
    $util = new Utility();              
    $util->detectMobileBrowser();   
    $util->checkWebSiteLanguageInCookies(); 
    $this->layout = "masterLayout";

    $count = '0';
    $id = Yii::app()->user->getState('id');
    $searchsort = "REJ";
    $sort = new CDbCriteria();
    $sort->addSearchCondition('status', $searchsort); 
    $sort->addCondition('developer_id='.$id);
    $models = GamesDevelopersApp::model()->findAll($sort,array('developer_id'=>$id)); 
    $this->render('/register/applist',array('models'=>$models,'count'=>$count));

}
```

It seems that everything worked fine, if I missed something in my code please tell me. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a combination how you have called [`compare`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#compare-detail) and added additional parameters to [`findAll`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAll-detail).

Your `compare` should be as follows:

```
$sort->compare('developer_id', $id);
```

And your `findAll` should be:

```
 $models = GamesDevelopersApp::model()->findAll($sort);
```

You could also use `addCondition` as follows:

```
$sort->addCondition('developer_id=:developer_id');
$sort->params[':developer_id'] = $id;
```

Comment: sorry that I putting wrong code ... actually im using addCondition... so I have to change to compare ?

Comment: But your solution is worked !!! thanks u so much I will change all addCondition to compare ... =)

Comment: You don't have to change all of them. I have updated the code to include an example of how you would implement `addCondition`. Clearly `compare` is easier.

Comment: yeah thanks ... but now I found out I have the another same error but code different, that one I doesn't use any of addCondition or compare, can u help me take a look ?

Comment: Ok. Add it as a new question and indicate that it is a followup of this one.

Comment: yeah I wish to post a new question but have to wait 90min to post a new question

Comment: I use the same solution to fixed the problem ~ thanks u again =)